# Opencart frond-end works well but admin returns blank page

Tags: php, opencart

I am confused by my opencart website, as I migrated my website from a ftp server to my localhost using MAMP I couldn't get it work since /admin returns me just black page. I have checked my PHP logs:
[image: PHP log]

```
[23-Jul-2015 12:48:16 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/uta/admin/index.php on line 151
[23-Jul-2015 12:48:16 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/uta/admin/index.php on line 152
[23-Jul-2015 12:48:16 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/uta/admin/index.php on line 156
[23-Jul-2015 12:48:16 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/uta/admin/index.php on line 157
[23-Jul-2015 12:48:16 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/uta/system/library/Translation.php on line 371
[23-Jul-2015 12:48:16 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/uta/system/library/Translation.php on line 371
[23-Jul-2015 12:48:16 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/uta/system/library/Translation.php on line 371
[23-Jul-2015 12:48:16 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/uta/system/library/Translation.php on line 371
```

Here is my admin/index.php:
[image]

```
 $config->set('config_language_id', $languages[$code]['language_id']);
 $config->set('config_admin_language', $languages[$code]['code']);
 $config->set('config_language_default', $languages['fr']['language_id']);

    // Language
 $language = new Language($languages[$config->get('config_admin_language')]     ['directory']);
 $language->load($languages[$config->get('config_admin_language')]['filename']);
 $registry->set('language', $language);
```

And Translation.php:
[image]

```
  private function loadFile($language_id, $filename)

{

    $code = $this->languages[$language_id]['code'];

    $file = $this->lang_root . $code . '/' . $filename . $this->file_ext;

    if (file_exists($file)) {

        $_lang = array();

        include $file;

        $this->translations[$filename][$language_id] = $_lang;

    } else {

        $this->translations[$filename][$language_id] = array();

    }



}
```

While I am pretty sure that my 2 config.php is right configured, if it is not right, php log will return me some errors I assume.

So are there anyone who can give me a hint about what this notice means? And how to get /admin works well.
Thank you in advance.

error_log(var_export($languages, true)) shows me:

```
array (
  'en' => 
  array (
    'language_id' => '1',
    'name' => 'English',
    'code' => 'en',
    'locale' => 'en_US.UTF-8,en_US,en-gb,english',
    'image' => 'gb.png',
    'directory' => 'english',
    'filename' => 'startup',
    'sort_order' => '1',
    'status' => '1',
  ),
  'fr' => 
  array (
    'language_id' => '2',
    'name' => 'Français',
    'code' => 'fr',
    'locale' => 'fr_CA.UTF-8,fr_FR.UTF-8,fr_CA,fr_FR,fr-fr,french',
    'image' => 'fr.png',
    'directory' => 'french',
    'filename' => 'startup',
    'sort_order' => '0',
    'status' => '1',
  ),
  'ru' => 
  array (
    'language_id' => '3',
    'name' => 'Russian',
    'code' => 'ru',
    'locale' => 'ru,ru_RU,ru_RU.UTF-8',
    'image' => 'ru.png',
    'directory' => 'russian',
    'filename' => 'startup',
    'sort_order' => '2',
    'status' => '1',
  ),
)
```

error_log(var_export($this->languages, true)) shows me:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'code' => 'en',
    'name' => 'English',
    'img' => 'gb.png',
    'id' => '1',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'code' => 'fr',
    'name' => 'Français',
    'img' => 'fr.png',
    'id' => '2',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'code' => 'ru',
    'name' => 'Russian',
    'img' => 'ru.png',
    'id' => '3',
  ),
)
```

Comment: You should probably edit your post to include the code itself, instead of just an unsearchable screenshot.

Comment: Hi @Huey I just edited it.

Comment: Please execute this query `update \`oc_setting\` set \`value\` = '1'  where \`key\` = 'config_error_display'`, this will show the **actual** errors stopping the script from executing

Comment: @AbdoAdel I dont have setting table in my database, but even i added it, admin is still blank page and returned me the same error.

Comment: first: all OC versions have settings table so I think that you are looking at something else, second: can you dump `$this->languages` using `error_log(var_export($this->languages, true))` and post the output here?

Comment: error_log(var_export($languages, true)) shows me the 3 arrays as shown above just edited my post @AbdoAdel

Comment: I have fixed all the notices, but admin still showing blank page. so it might the problem of configuration? @AbdoAdel

Comment: I don't know really it's very hard to determine such an error without access to the project, you can try logging messages at some check points in **admin/index,php**, for example`error_log('point 1')` at the beginning of the file `error_log('point 2')` later and so on, this will help to know where the script stops executing, and you are right that it may be *problem of configuration*

Comment: As I did what you said and I found even the header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
doesn't show up. But in index of the frond well it shows. do you have some clues?thanks @AbdoAdel

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem, seems due to some cookie and session problems.